# How to install manually vsix (2011) in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to install a vsix add-in in VS2012. However it looks like this add-in is available only for VS2010.

Is there any way to install it manually or to force it to work on 2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VSIX is just a zip-archive. Unpack it, locate the file `extension.vsixmanifest`. This is an XML file, open it. Locate the section `SupportedProducts`. It should look like the following:

```
    <SupportedProducts>
        <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
            <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
            <Edition>Premium</Edition>
            <Edition>Pro</Edition>
        </VisualStudio>
    </SupportedProducts>
```

Copy-paste the `VisualStudio` section and update the `Version` attribute on the pasted fragment to `11.0`.

Pack the contents back into a zip-archive. Make sure the archive have the VSIX extension. You're done.