# Padded cursor in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2015, editing

Is there a similar plugin to John Nastase's Padded Cursor, that work on recent versions of Visual Studio (2015)?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnNastase.PaddedCursor

I want to keep my cursor from hitting bottom of the editor window, so I can always see 5-6 lines more.

Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269980/how-to-install-manually-vsix-2011-in-visual-studio-2012 For Visual Studio 2015 you can try to add Version="14.0" to the manifest.

Comment: That worked, thanks! For other readers: modify only Visual Studio version, and keep VisualStudio.MPF version as is.